# How to connect to sqlite3 db in python with user, password and host name

Tags: python, sqlite

I am beginning with sqlite3 in Python.
I know how to connect to local database. See simple example below:

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

But now I would like to send data into a database that is running on a server. I have following config information:

```
[db-my_db]
user=my_user
password=my_pass
host=db.my_db.com
database=my_db.com
```

How can I connect to this database? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing what database is running on the server, it's hard to say. Sqlite doesn't have networking components in itself, so you can't just "run Sqlite on a server" like you can e.g. MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: SQLite does not have network connectivity by itself. So you seem to want to connect to a different database - but we do not know which. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: OK, thanks for making it clear to me. I will take a look on MySQL or PostgreSQL